# MySQL - how "for each row" statements get executed for multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

**Description**
I have a before update trigger to fill `updated_at` field to log update time. I used the `for each row` statement and expected each row to have a different timestamp. But if I update multiple rows in one statement, all rows get same timestamp.

**Example**
For the following table and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

delimiter $$
create trigger foo_before_update before update on `foo`
for each row begin
  set new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now(6)) * 1000000;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and existing data:

```
+----+-----+------------+
| id | bar | updated_at |
+----+-----+------------+
|  1 | a   | 0          |
|  2 | b   | 0          |
|  3 | c   | 0          |
+----+-----+------------+
```

When I run `UPDATE foo SET bar = 'd';`, I expect
to have three different timestamp but I got:

```
+----+-----+------------------+
| id | bar | updated_at       |
+----+-----+------------------+
|  1 | d   | 1536903279930403 |
|  2 | d   | 1536903279930403 |
|  3 | d   | 1536903279930403 |
+----+-----+------------------+
```

**My Question**
I'm using mysql 5.7 and from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> The statement following FOR EACH ROW defines the trigger body; that
>   is, the statement to execute each time the trigger activates, which
>   occurs once for each row affected by the triggering event.

I want to know what causes the timestamps to be the same:

- Dose mysql execute statement once and apply to all affected rows as an optimization?
- Or it executes those rows one by one but still get the same time? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **want** different times for each row, you need to use [`SYSDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate). From the manual for [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> (Within a stored function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which
>   the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs
>   from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which returns the exact time at which
>   it executes.